# how to get sum and lowest date from the List<> with lambda

Tags: java, lambda

```
public class BusinessLog {

private Date logDate;
private double prize;

}
```

Given the object BusinessLog, I need to have sum for all the prizes in `List<BusinessLog> list` also need to return the lowest date from the list, is it possible with lambda,

I can do it with forEach for sure, but how to do it with lambda,

What I tried to do until now is ,

```
    BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    if (list != null) {
        list.forEach(businessLog -> {
            balance.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(businessLog.getPrize()));
            // how to get lowest date 

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A solution using streaming

To find the minimum date, you can do something like this:

```
Optional<Date> minDate = list.stream().map(v -> v.logDate).min(Date::compareTo);
```

And to calculate the sum:

```
double sum = list.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.prize).sum();
```

I wouldn't worry about "optimizing" this and trying to do it in one loop unless this is provably a major bottleneck in your system (unlikely). Keeping the two ideas separate makes the code easier to understand and maintain.

#### Your use of BigDecimal

Your code for doing `balance.add(...)` to a `BigDecimal` won't actually work the way you've written it because the `add` method on `BigDecimal` returns a new instance rather than mutating the existing instance. `BigDecimal` instances are immutable. You can't assign a new value to `balance` because it's effectively `final` from the context of the lambda.

The idea of using `BigDecimal` is a good one though. You should avoid using `double` for anything where exact decimal places are important (e.g. money). If you change `prize` to a BigDecimal you can't use `sum()` but you can use `reduce()` to fulfil the same function.

```
BigDecimal sum = list.stream().map(v -> v.prize).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Very well explained, about BigDecimal thanks, I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

To compute multiple custom aggregations, you should write a custom reducer.

For example, the following reducer calculates the stats in one `BusinessLog` object. The following supposes a constructor `public BusinessLog(double prize, Date logDate)` to be declared.

```
BusinessLog stats = 
        bl.stream()
        .reduce((log1, log2) -> new BusinessLog(
                log1.getPrize() + log2.getPrize(),
                log1.getLogDate().before(log2.getLogDate()) ?
                     log1.getLogDate() : log2.getLogDate()
            )).get();

Date lowestDate = stats.getLogDate();
double prizeSum = stats.getPrize();
```

Please note that Using `BusinessLog` as a temporary stats holder is essentially a hack. You'd need to design a separate class for that purpose.

Comment: But then at the same time I need lowest date as well, so do I write the lambda expression again for date?

Comment: @tyro you could build a custom collector for that, but you can also stream twice

Comment: @tyro Added an example that uses a reducer to calculate both aggregations in one stream traversal

Comment: @ErnestKiwele can't tell why the downvote here... take a +1 from me. btw, you can't easily create a dedicate class for that, how will you specify an identity for `Date`?

Comment: @Eugene Thanks (the post was edited). I believe there's no "identity" concern for the reduce operation. All that's need is combining two objects into a new one. But you're right, a dedicated class isn't needed, just a data structure that's easy to "reduce".

Comment: @ErnestKiwele exactly my point, let's imagine that you are reducing to `SimpleEntry` as it holds two values, right? What would this constructor take as arguments? For `BigInteger` it's easy, but for `Date`? You need to specify an identity ... I don't know an "identity" for Date

Comment: @Eugene I think I see what you're saying. Correct me if I misunderstood. There wouldn't be a generic "date identity", but one can conceive of a sort of identity for the reduce operation at hand. In this case of "min", a reducer can decide to use null as identity, assuming it's correctly implemented (I do see how brittle that code will be). But I agree that from there things stop making sense very quickly, making that class useless beyond the context of that reduction.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele exactly. The other answer makes use of null as identity, but its as ugly as it can get...

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele Thanks for your reply, but like the idea of keeping them  separate loop